# Using methods that return a constant value

Tags: java

Do we really need static final constants in Java?

Assume I have the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static final int A = 1234;

    public static int getA()
    {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

Can you please compare the following two cases in terms of efficiency?

1. `Test.A`
2. `Test.getA()`

Comment: http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/19/4-major-principles-of-object-oriented-programming/

Comment: I'm curious about what the bytecode comes out to be. A `static` method returning a `static final` variable seems highly optimizable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming a JIT compiler, there should be no noticeable difference in efficiency - at least not enough to make a significant difference in the execution speed of your application.

There is a noticeable gain in flexibility, though: encapsulating the value in a method is nearly always good, because it lets you change the way the value is calculate later.

A notable exception to this rule is pure constants, say, from the world of mathematics: it does not make much sense to encapsulate access to `Math.PI`, because there is no chance that the value of this fundamental constant is going to change, prompting a need to switch the method the value is obtained in your program.

Comment: Especially since references to constants are copied verbatim to code that uses them, so if a constant changes, any code that uses it must be recompiled to get the new value.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` `final` constants behave differently than literal values returned from a method. The java compiler also uses these in certain cases **at compile time**.

One example,

```
public static boolean DEBUG = false;

...

if (DEBUG)
{
   ...do something...
}
```

vs.

```
public boolean debug()
{
    return false;
}

...

if (debug())
{
    ...do something 2...
}
```

In the first case, the condition and ...do something... code will not be included in the compiled byte-code (the class file). In the second case, the condition and ...do something 2... code will be included but never execute - the JIT may do sufficient analysis in this case though to remove the code at runtime.

At one time, in the early days of Java, the JIT didn't exist or was not smart enough to optimize out the simple method that returns a literal value. Then a constant value was needed for performance. It's also more convenient to define constants this way if you keep in mind that external classes (for public/protected static final constants) will have the value baked in to that byte-code at compile time; rather than getting the value from the source class at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, `test.getA()` can often be reduced to the equivalent of `test.A` by JIT. Still, the difference would be neglectable at best.

> Do we really need static final constants in Java?

No, but it helps to prevent repeated allocation.

Comment: The JIT will indeed optimize this, but this is not [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).

Comment: @Jesper, after refreshing my memory on the topic, I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

Static final variables cannot be changed by external code, so there's no need to encapsulate them.

Also, a static method with no parameters suggest access to an object's state, which is a lie, since the method is static.

Compiler-wise there should not be much difference in efficiency, but in regards of program legibility and self-documenting code, static final is a better and time tested option.

Answer (score 0):

The case you show is fairly trivial, which I believe is intended. Your first case is more direct and efficient as it is one less call on the stack, but I believe better coding style would be to combine the two. I assume this is not going to be the only place you use this variable in your class.

```
public class Test {

public static final int A = 1234;

public static int getA()
{
   return A;
}

public static int doSomething()
{
   int result = A * 10;
   //do more stuff
   return result;
}
}
```

This allows you to only change your variable in one place if it ever needs changing and get the expected result throughout your program. Personally, I would make the int A private just for consistency of using a get method, which is how must classes are set up. This way you will never run into a problem where you can't remember if you need '()' after the variable name and all variables that live outside the class are accessed in the same manner. Most of this is just coding style and not either right or wrong.